# Overloading Methods With Different Behavior - Style

Tags: c#, coding-style, method-overloading

I have a style question about overloading methods/constructors. I have a constructor which 
does something very simple, and then calls a method with some side effects. Sometimes however I don't want the side effects so I made a separate overloaded constructor. I show two versions here. Version 1 is simple: if I pass any bool then TrickyFunction won't be called. But maybe that's confusing, because the value of no_tricks does not affect the behavior (only that no_tricks exists). Version 2 actually does process no_tricks and makes a decision to run TrickyFunction based on that.

Which version, or another version, is more stylistically "correct?"

```
public foo MyFunction(string a)
{
    variable = a
    TrickyFunction(a)
}

#Version 1
public foo MyFunction(string a, bool no_tricks)
{
    variable = a
}

#Version 2
public foo MyFunction(string a, bool no_tricks)
{
    variable = a
    if (notricks == true)
    {
        TrickyFunction(a)
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, there is no reason for `== true`, just write `if (no_tricks)`.

Comment: huge code smell that I cannot comment on since none of the actual code is here. And by passing a bool to perform the same action a different way is revealing something about the internal workings of the function which is the obvious smell. If the method can produce different results (e.g. the side effects you mentioned) then it isn't the same method and shouldn't be an overload. Create a similarly named method where the name indicates that the results are a bit different.

Answer (score 3):

Version #2 is **FAR** preferable, although the overall design is often considered a code smell.

Note that more recent C# dialects allow for optional parameters, so you could combine your base and overload.

```
class foo {
  public foo(string a, bool no_tricks = false) {
    variable = a;
    if(no_tricks == false) {
      TrickyFunction(a);
    }
  }
}
```

(And, of course, note that passing a false value to override default is kinda counter-intuitive by itself, especially when your logical value doens't match the name of the variable, as in your text.)

Answer (score 0):

Version 2, kinda.

I would only have one constructor, but the second parameter `doExtraWork` is optional, and defaulted to true. This follows the general guideline that boolean true should represent doing things rather than not doing things. And this approach would simplify your code. If optional params are forbidden in your codebase, then just have the "little" constructor call the other.

Though I'd look to remove tricky stuff from *any* constructor - do just enough to initialize your invariants.

Answer (score 0):

While C# does not allow a type to have multiple constructors except by giving them all different signatures, types can have any number of factory methods.  My inclination would be to have a protected constructor with a "noTricks" parameter, but have consumers of the class use factory methods to construct instances.  Tricky and non-tricky methods can then be given different names to clarify their behavior.